# How to extract the year and quarter from the String date in databricks SQL

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

Can someone show me how to extract the year from the String date in databricks SQL.

I am based in the UK and our date format is normally as follows:

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

The field containing the dates is set as StringType()

I am trying to extract the year from the string as follows:

```
select year(cast(financials_0_accountsDate as Date)) from `financiallimited_csv`
```

I'm using the following the code to extract the quarter

```
select quarter(cast(financials_0_accountsDate as Date)) from `financiallimited_csv`
```

However, both result in NULL values.

Any thoughts on how to extract the year and quarter from dates with StringType() dd/mm/yyyy?

The table looks like the following:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try the [to_date](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/to_date.html) function?

```
select year(to_date(financials_0_accountsDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy')) from `financiallimited_csv`
```